# Which data structure for linking text with audio in Java

Tags: java, audio

I want to write a program in which plays an audio file that reads a text. 
I want to highlite the current syllable that the audiofile plays in green and the rest of the current word in red.
What kind of datastructure should I use to store the audio file and the information that tells the program when to switch to the next word/syllable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly left-field suggestion, but have you looked at Karaoke software? It may not be seen as "serious" enough, but it sounds very similar to what you're doing. For example, [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.net/) is a subtitling program that lets you create subtitles in the SSA/ASS format. It has karaoke tools for hilighting the chosen word or part.

It's most commonly used for subtitling anime, but it also works for audio provided you have a suitable player. These are sadly quite rare on the Mac.

The format looks similar to the one proposed by Yuval A:

```
{\K132}Unmei {\K34}no {\K54}tobira
{\K60}{\K132}yukkuri {\K36}to {\K142}hirakareta
```

The lengths are durations rather than absolute offsets. This makes it easier to shift the start of the line without recalculating all the offsets. The double entry indicates a pause.

Is there a good reason this needs to be part of your Java program, or is an off the shelf solution possible?

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple data structure that describes what next batch of letters consists of the next syllable and the time stamp for switching to that syllable?

Just a quick example:

[0:00] This [0:02] is [0:05] an [0:07] ex- [0:08] am- [0:10] ple

Answer (score 1):

To highlight part of word sounds like you're getting into [phonetics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetics) which are sounds that make up words.  It's going to be really difficult to turn a sound file into something that will "read" a text.  Your best bet is to use the text itself to drive a phonetics based engine, like FreeTTS which is based off of the [Java Speech API](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-guide/index.html).

To do this you're going to have to take the text to be read, split it into each phonetic syllable and play it.  so "syllable" is "syl" "la" "ble".  Playing would be; highlight syl, say it and move to next one.

This is really "old-skool" its been done on the original Apple II the same way.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to get familiar with FreeTTS -- this open source tool : http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php -

You might want to feed only a few words to the TTS engine at a given point of time -- highlight them and once those are SPOKEN out, de-highlight them and move to the next batch of words.

BR,
~A

Comment: I don't want a synthesic voice, but I want to use a preexisting audio file of the text in question.